# Python-3: Interactive plot

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of sentences. I want to embed them to 2-dimensions data (using word2vec or tf-idf with t-SNE for instance) then plot them.

I want to have an interactive plot, i.e. when I hover the mouse to a point it will show the content of the original sentence.

What framework or libraries in Python can help me to do so?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly/)

[Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Both can be used to create interactive plots/charts.